# How to make space between elements?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I use bootstrap3 in my project.

I have this html elements:

```
    <form class="form-inline">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-group">

                <span class="input-group-addon">from-</span>
               <input  id="input1" class="form-control input-sm" type="text/>

                <!--How can I make here space-->

                <span id="span2" class="input-group-addon">to-</span
                <input class="form-control input-sm" type="text" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Here is working [PLUNKER](https://plnkr.co/edit/4LNxsdDc3kO1r1I4Rx3q?p=preview).

As you can see I have spans and inputs inside form element.How can I make space between element with id =`input1` and span with id = "span2"?

Answer (score 2):

The problem was with how you grouped elements. Just wrap each of your span and input with a div that has `class="input-group"`

Here is the [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VKqwEL)

HTML

```
<form class="form-inline">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon">from-</span>
        <input id="input1" class="form-control input-sm" type="text" />
    </div>

      <!--How can I make here space-->
      <div class="input-group">
        <span id="span2" class="input-group-addon">to-</span>
        <input class="form-control input-sm" type="text" />
      </div>

  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add another element in there, like:

```
<div id="spacer"></div>
```

with a style like

```
#spacer { width: 14px; display:table-cell;}
```